# Why return value of some methods such as: add(E), remove(Object), addAll,... is boolean in Collection FrameWork?

Tags: java, collections

I'm a stupid student. I have a question that is the title. 
I think when I do this, return boolean or not has no affect on me:

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.add("whatever");
lst.remove("whatever");
```

And here is remove method(Which overrides from Collection< E > interface) of Arraylist Class in the API:

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            if (elementData[index] == null) {
                fastRemove(index);
                return true;
            }
    } else {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
                fastRemove(index);
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I think if in Collection< E > interface, designers of the framework write `public void remove(Object o);` is ok but they have to have a certain purpose and I don't understand. Return boolean for what? Please tell me

Comment: Returned `boolean` value tells you that whether the element **contained** the given element .Have a look at `ArrayList` official documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of remove:

It exactly tells you whether any object was removed from your collection or it wasn't.

In the case of add:

It's helpful in `collections` like `Set`, because it returns `true` if a new element added to the set, and it returns `false`, if the object is already in the collection.

From HashSet:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return (this.map.put(e, PRESENT) == null);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

At times, the client code might not know if the object to be removed is part of the collection. This client code would certainly like to know the effect of the remove operation. Hence, the design decision to return a boolean.

-- edit
For example,
Suppose, a synchronized collection is shared between two threads. One populates it and the other removes objects from it. The removing thread would like to know if the removal was successful.

Comment: please give me some examples for using boolean value is returned in the client code.

Answer (score 0):

`remove(o)` return false if o was not found in the collection.